# How to find unique values in a vector c++

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures

I am trying to solve a coding problem where I am to check and see if a vector has unique values and if it does then return true else false.

So Far I thought of using a nested loops where you would compare the first to the last, but I am wanted to know if C++  has anything else then doing a o(n^2) type iteration. I saw that c++ has a  unique function, but that would delete the unique value.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,1]
Output: true
Example 2:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: false

Comment: Sort then a single pass, or create a set and check to see if it exists before adding each element. Both of course require extra memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what exactly your task is. The description is not very clear and seems to contradict the examples. _"see if a vector has unique values and if it does then return true else false."_ - all numbers in example 2 are unique, yet the expected answer is `false`. Example 1 also has unique numbers (2, 3 are unique), but this one returns `true`.

Comment: Also _"I saw that c++ has a unique function, but that would delete the unique value."_ - why do you think that? See [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), it actually _preserves_ the unique values by moving them to the front of the range. However, behaviour is undefined, if the range isn't sorted.

Comment: @churill its not undefined, rahter `std::unique` only cares about consecutive duplictes (ie it has to be sorted). It is undefined when the binary predicate is not an equivalence relation

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh, yes, you are right, didn'texpect that!

Comment: @churill me neither ;) I think I confused it with `std::binary_search` wich is ub without sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) checks for consecutive duplicates and moves them to the end of the range. It does not remove them from the vector. Anyhow you can make a copy. It also returns an iterator to the end of the range of unique values (that are now in the front of the vector):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool only_unique(std::vector<int> v) {
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    return std::unique(v.begin(),v.end()) == v.end();
}

int main(){
    std::cout << only_unique({1,2,3,1});  
    std::cout << only_unique({1,2,3,4});      
}
```

If you don't want to use the additional memory you can change the argument to a reference. Currently, `only_unique` leaves the parameter unmodified. Even if the vector is passed by reference the duplicates will still be present (just at a different position). This has `O(n log n)` complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I clearly did not understand the purpose of the unique function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create "set" structure,
it makes it possible to insert values from vector and does not insert the duplicates,
so you can check if the size of the set and the vector match or not.

```
set<int> st;
for (auto i : nums)
    st.insert(i);
return st.size() == nums.size();
```